# Can't bind Svelte variable to a meter element

Tags: svelte-3

I get the error:

```
[!] (plugin svelte) ValidationError: 'value' is not a valid binding on <meter> elements
```

This is my relevant HTML template code within the component:

```
<meter id="meter" bind:value={score} min="0" max="100" low="25" high="75" optimum="80">
</meter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Svelte is correct, meter elements are not interactive and thus it makes no sense to bind to their value since the user can't change it. Perhaps you're looking for `<input type="range" />`?

Comment: Well rather than bind the element's value, can't I just set it in Svelte/JavaScript?

Comment: @gornvix Attributes set to variables are automatically made reactive to variable changes in Svelte. That is, all attributes are one-way bindings. The bind keyword is only to make it two-way, that is, for changes to the attribute from outside to also be saved in your script's variable.